# How to autodisplay an url when a style.display get on "block"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a function (maybe an onload()?) to autodisplay an url instead of having to click the link . I want it to happen when the display gets on style.display="block"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKMTw.png)

Comment: Can you show some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's a login, when you log a final display apears where u can click the <a href > to acces de php, but i'm trying to make it so when that display blocks it automaticcally redirects you to the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could change the url with javascript: ```window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";```

Comment: Where should i try that? I've tried to create a function autodispllay(url){ url="myurl.com" return url) and call it on the html with an onload=autodiplay() (inside the div that displays)

Comment: Please post code as actual code, do not post pictures of code. The easiest way is to surround code with ```